# Class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a loop that needs to sleep before continuing to the next iteration, so I multiply the seconds * 60 to get the number of minutes.  Instead of doing something like "sleep 10 * 60" for ten minutes, I want to make it a little prettier.  I'm trying to do this:  "sleep 10.minutes".  I don't want to do this:  "sleep minutes(10)"

I'm trying to override Fixnum to add a method called 'minutes', but I can't grab the '15' from '15.minutes'.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
class Fixnum
  def minutes
    15 # need to find out the value entered here
  end
end
```

The code above works, but I have to return the value I want inside of Fixnum.minutes - how do I find out what number was entered before .minutes?

I don't want to pass an argument because it looks different.

Comment: Such time based extensions to `Numeric`s are provided by [`ActiveSupport`](http://apidock.com/rails/Numeric/minutes). Perhaps you should just use that instead of rolling your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def minutes
    self * 60
  end
end
```

Then `15.minutes` would return `15 * 60`.

Comment: So here `self` points to `15`, which is the Fixnum object you invoke `#minutes` with.

Comment: Oh my.  That should have been obvious but I couldn't think of the answer!!  Thanks - it works perfectly.